# Vue2: Reacting on non existing input elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a validation that lets form fields pass depending on different field setups. In this example the location2 input does not exist, so the Vue valid method never returns a true.
My form is server side dynamic so i get two sets of different fields. Sometimes location2 is there and than it should be checked inside Vue and sometimes its not there and it should not be checked. I don't know if there is something inside Vue i can do this with. I allready tried using outside `Vue.set(App, 'location2', 'Test');` depending on the field existence but that's not very nice.

I hope this is understandable :)

```
<div id="app">   
  <input name="location" v-model="location" value="" type="text" required="required">
  <br />
  <!-- <input name="location2" v-model="location2" value="" type="text"required="required"> -->
  <p>
    Location: {{location}}
    <br /> Location2: {{location2}}
  </p>
  <button type="submit" :disabled="valid()">Go</button>
</div>
```

sd

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    location: '',
    location2: ''
  },
  methods: {
    valid: function() {

      return !(this.location != '' && this.location2 != '');
    }
  },
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bf1ge2xt/

Comment: How are you deciding whether the input for `location2` is rendered or not?

Answer (score 0):

If the `name` attribute of your inputs are always going to match the data properties of your Vue component, your `valid` method could go through each `input` in the component and check if the property with the same name is valid:

```
valid: function() {
  let inputs = this.$el.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (this[inputs[i].name] == '') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bf1ge2xt/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do a check to see if this.location2 is set?

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    location: '',
    location2: ''
  },
  methods: {
    valid: function() {
      if (this.location2) {
        return !(this.location != '' && this.location2 != '');
      }
      return this.location == '';
    }
  },
})
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/g92Lscu4/1/